# Rest application using hateoas: Multiple markers at this line

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, lombok

I am trying to make a rest application using **hateoas**.

Here is my assembelr class:

```
public class PlantInventoryEntryAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<PlantInventoryEntry, PlantInventoryEntryDTO>
{ 
}
```

**PlantInventoryEntryDTO** class is:

```
@Data
public class PlantInventoryEntryDTO  extends ResourceSupport{

    Long id;
    String name;
    String description;
    @Column(precision = 8, scale = 2)
    BigDecimal price;

    public Long idGetter (){

        return  id;
    }
}
```

the problem is, in line `@Data` (i use lombok) i have faced with the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - overrides org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport.equals
    - The return type is incompatible with ResourceSupport.getId()
    - Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If 
     this is intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.
    - overrides org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport.toString
    - overrides org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport.hashCode
    - overrides org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport.getId
```

How can i handle it?

**Update**:

**PlantInventoryEntry**  class

```
@Entity
@Data
public class PlantInventoryEntry {

    @EmbeddedId
    PlantInventoryEntryID id;

    String name;
    String description;

    @Column(precision = 8, scale = 2)
    BigDecimal price;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename the field `id` in `PlantInventoryEntryDTO` (to, say, `entryId`).

The only error in those "multiple markers" is `The return type is incompatible with ResourceSupport.getId()`, the others are warnings.

`ResourceSupport` defines a [getId() method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/ResourceSupport.java#L46) with a return type of `Link`. Lombok tries to add another getId() method with the return type `long` for the `id` field in `PlantInventoryEntryDTO`. Since their return types are incompatible, the compiler won't override the original method.